# Java ActionCommand equivalent for FocusListener

Tags: java, events, command, focus, listener

I have to extend some code which implements an ActionListener that uses ActionCommands to get further information about the object to which the component that triggered the ActionEvent belongs to.

The same piece of code should now also implement a FocusListener, so I need my FocusListener to receive something like an ActionCommand from the component that triggered the FocusEvent.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to the ActionCommand for a FocusListener, so I'm a bit stuck. How can I provide my FocusListener with something similar to an ActionCommand?

Comment: What other information do you need? Similar to an ActionEvent, you can get the Component that fired the FocusListener event of a via the FocusEvent.getComponent() method

Comment: Thank you, I should have mentioned that getComponent(), getSource(), getParent(), getClass(), etc. are not applicable for my purpose.
Every object that has this listener gets a unique ID on initialization, which is stored in the ActionCommand and by this accessible by the ActionListener.
This is what I need for my FocusListener, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FocusEvent.getComponent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html) method retrieves the Component that fired the event. This may not directly provide the appropriate 'command' you wish, but you can indirectly retrieve the data associated with the Component that fired the event (eg the Component returned by the getComponent method) by:

1. Mapping each component to its ID using a Map (eg HashMap)
2. Setting the name of each Component to it's ID, and use the getName method
3. If the component extends AbstractButton, you can cast to that type and use the getActionCommand method.

Comment: Option two, the idea of using the Component's name, is amazingly simple and works fine for my purpose.